# Yii - Controller in subdirectory

Tags: yii

I'm facing an issue with Yii Framework routing.

I've created controller, let's call it TestController.php

Then, I need to put it into a subdirectory called Make, so my structure would look like:

```
controllers/TestController.php
controllers/Make/TestController.php
```

Of ocurse, if I change it's name, it works perfectly but is there any way to put a controller of the same name in controllers directory and a subdirectory?

**Edit**
My URLManager config looks like:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'gii' => 'gii',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>' => 'gii/<controller>',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' =>                                                      'gii/<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

I have a controller `Bookmarks`. As I have some other things related to the bookmarks, I needed to create a directory `bookmarks` and put some controllers there, for example `Categories`.

Can't force to make it work.

**Edit 2**
Just checked clean application. It seems to be a Yii bug (?).

**Edit 3**
I've changed import configuration, as suggested:

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.controllers.bookmarks.*'
    ),
```

I have also created a correct route rule `'bookmarks/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'bookmarks/<controller>/<action>',`.

My files structure is now as following:

```
BookmarksController.php
bookmarks/CategoriesController.php
```

Here's an exceptions that's being thrown:

> exception 'CHttpException' with message 'The system is unable to find
>   the requested action "categories".' in
>   /home/root/www/yiitesting/framework/web/CController.php:477

Comment: I have asked a question on official YIi support forum. Here's the link: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/21440-controller-and-subdirectory-conflict/. I also tried to reproduce this issue (as posted on the forums) and faced the same issue. It seems that's impossible doing such functionality using Yii - which seems to be really weird for me - I cannot quarantee it's correct answer as I just started using Yii few days ago (which was no problem but basically do not have enough experience with this framework to provide a useful answer).

Comment: what url are you trying to reach for "bookmarks/CategoriesController.php"? If you go to bookmarks/Categories it should look for a actionIndex in the CategoriesController. Make sure you put your "bookmarks" ULR rule first. It should be basically the same routing as Gii, so if that's working for you, this should as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before making any subdirectory, be aware that Yii autoload function doesn't search subdirectories: Yii want to autoload the TestController class in the case of Controller, so add application.controllers.Make.* in your import declaration:

```
'import'=>array(
     .....
     'application.controllers.Make.*',
 ),
```

and of course you must add a rule to urlManager to help Yii look up correct Controller like @ldg did.

notes: in this case, Yii will look for views/Make/* for the view.

Comment: It's normal behave! What's your expect here? you have only one /bookmarks/ prefix and you want to share between two Controllers? if you put your route rule for /bookmarks/ before default route ("<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>" => .. ) you can access your /bookmarks/categories/ as normal, but CategoriesControler is unusable !

Comment: You are completely right. My approach was wrong for some reason. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to update your URL Manager with an entry like:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'rules'=>array(
  'Make/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'Make/<controller>/<action>',
  ...
```

then access that controller via /Make/test[/action]

Comment: Unfortunately, `xception 'CHttpException' with message 'The system is unable to find the
requested action "Test"`. It seems like Yii is ignoring my routing rules, it's trying to search for Test action in Test controller, but not for Make/Test controller. Weird.

Comment: I've temporarily solved it by creating MakeTest controller in controller's main directory but I think there must be some other way to solve that.

Comment: please post your url manager config and what url are you trying to open

Answer (score 1):

My nginx config:

> rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php last;

My Yii urlManager config:

> ```
>     'urlManager'=>array(
>         'urlFormat'=>'path',
>         'showScriptName' => false, 
>         'rules'=>array(
>               '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
>               '<path:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<path>/<controller>/<action>',
>             )
>         ),
> ```

The following urlManager config also works:

> ```
>     'urlManager'=>array(
>         'urlFormat'=>'path',
>         'showScriptName' => false,
>         'rules'=>array(
>               '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
>               '<abc:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<abc>/<controller>/<action>',
>             )
>         ),
> ```

Comment: I only did rules configuration and worked well
'<abc:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<abc>/<controller>/<action>'

I had to change paths on access control too...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing through /Make/test instead of /test? This feature should work out of the box. Cheers

Comment: Yes, of course I tried. The exceptions has been thrown - action cannot be found. It seems that Yii is searching for an action in TestController and ignoring Make/TestController. Any ideas?

Comment: I used the gii module to add both TestController and Make/TestController (see a screen [here](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/9113/pantallazo3dr.png)) and it just worked to me. You could still create a module called Make if you see there are lots of controllers that could go inside module. However, it's not its main use, it can work that way.

Comment: Yes, let's ignore everything else for now. I was also using Gii, but the routing is not working. Please see my comment to ldg's answer.